# Excel-VBA: strange behavior of Offset

Tags: vba, excel, offset

I'm encountering some strange behavior when I try to offset a range.

In the immediate window in a new document I can do the following:

```
?Range("A15:A16").Offset(-8).Address
```

which returns:

```
$A$7:$A$8
```

as it should.

However, in my current workbook, the same code returns just $A$7.
The following code does work as it should:

```
?Range("A15,A16").Offset(-8).Address
```

(returns $A$7,$A$8)

```
?Range("A15:A17").Offset(-8).Address
```

(returns $A$7:$A$9).

Is there a setting that I'm missing that causes this strange behavior? Especially since it does work properly in a new workbook.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If A15:A16 are merged then it seems to replicate the undesired behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I've searched for the answer to this question for days now, and as soon as I posted the question I found the solution. It turned out the cells were merged in sets of 2. The offset only returns the address of the first cell of the merged set.

Comment: For merged origin cells, you could use `Range("A15").Offset(-8, 0).Resize(2, 1)`